# Managing access to devices using a website

Tags: php, rdp, access-rights, guacamole

I'd like to manage access to multiple devices (PCs) using a website.
User has to be logged in into the website and has certain rights in order to access some device.
I was thinking about something like [Guacamole](http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/), but I'd like to have my own website manage access to devices.
I'd like to ask you if you have been solving this kind of issue, and what approach did you use to accomplish it.
Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: I was not sure if stackoverflow is right site to post this (I was considering webmasters or server fault), but as this is rather programming + some server part, I thought this is ok. Please feel free to redirect me if I'm wrong.